# Determine If Two Points Are Near

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, math

I have the following:

```
bool AreNear(Point Old, Point Current)
{
    int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(Old.X);
    int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(Current.X);
    int y1 = Convert.ToInt32(Old.Y);
    int y2 = Convert.ToInt32(Current.Y);
    if (x1 == x2) {
        if (y1 == y2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to return true in the function if the current point is in 25 pixels radius of the old point. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: PS: I would use a more descriptive name for the function, for example, `AreNear`. Otherwise the meaning of the statement `if (ComparePoints(old, current))` cannot be deduced without looking into the subroutine itself.

Comment: What type are `X` and `Y` ? String ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [the Pythagorean formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to calculate the distance between two points. In C#:

```
var d = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.Pow(y1 - y2, 2))
```

Why does this work? Have a look at the following diagram and remember that `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` holds for right triangles:

[image: Pythagoras]

Answer (score 5):

Just calculate the square of the distance using Pythagoras' theorem, and compare to the square of the radius:

```
bool ComparePoints(Point Old, Point Current)
{
    int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(Old.X);
    int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(Current.X);
    int y1 = Convert.ToInt32(Old.Y);
    int y2 = Convert.ToInt32(Current.Y);
    int dx = x1 - x2;
    int dy = y1 - y2;
    return (dx*dx + dy*dy) < 25*25;
}
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding those slooow square roots when they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Math.Abs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the distance:

```
public static bool InDistance(Point Old, Point Current, int distance)
{
    int diffX = Math.Abs(Old.X - Current.X);
    int diffY = Math.Abs(Old.Y - Current.Y);
    return diffX <= distance && diffY <= distance;
}
```

use it:

```
bool arePointsInDistance = InDistance(new Point(100, 120), new Point(120, 99), 25);
```

Comment: This checks whether the new point is within a `25` pixel *square* of the old point (i.e., it uses the maximum metric).

Comment: Nice alternative choice of metric :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the distance formula http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm and compare the distance <=25