# How to Return Resultset with a Given Radius

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL (SQL Server) and it works for the most part. The problem is I am really creating a square and not a true circle. My goal is to pass in a city and state which has a lat and long, then find all cities within a 100 mile radius of that lat long. The latitude and longitude are stored in the DB so all my values are there. I just need a more precise way of doing it. Here is my code thus far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_StoresByZipArea] (@zip nvarchar(5), @Radius float)  AS

DECLARE @LatRange float
DECLARE @LongRange float
DECLARE @LowLatitude float
DECLARE @HighLatitude  float
DECLARE @LowLongitude  float
DECLARE @HighLongitude  float

DECLARE @istartlat  float
DECLARE @istartlong  float

SELECT @iStartlat=Latitude, @iStartLong=Longitude from zipcodes where zipcode=@ZIP

SELECT @LatRange = @Radius / ((6076 / 5280) * 60)
SELECT @LongRange = @Radius / (((cos((@iStartLat * 3.141592653589 / 180)) * 6076.) /  5280.) * 60)

SELECT @LowLatitude = @istartlat - @LatRange
SELECT @HighLatitude = @istartlat + @LatRange
SELECT @LowLongitude = @istartlong - @LongRange
SELECT @HighLongitude = @istartlong + @LongRange

/** Now you can create a SQL statement which limits the recordset of cities in this manner:  **/

SELECT * FROM ZipCodes
 WHERE (Latitude <= @HighLatitude) AND (Latitude >= @LowLatitude) AND (Longitude >= @LowLongitude) AND (Longitude <= @HighLongitude)
```

Comment: I was about to suggest the [Pythagorean formula](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13032393/87698) (`SELECT * FROM ZipCodes
 WHERE ((Latitude - @istartlat) * (Latitude - @istartlat))
      + (Longitude - @istartlong) * (Longitude - @istartlong)) 
      <= (@Radius * @Radius)`), but then I realized that this is more complicated due to the conversion from Lat/Long to miles.

Comment: Perhaps have sql return the cities in the square, then add precision by filtering on the application side. It's probably not good to have sql do so much number crunching especially for large amounts of clients. Adding more app servers is cheap.

Comment: Distances between cities wont change very often, so feel free to cache all of these results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the great circle distance to do this in the past.  The implementation below tells you the distance between two different points, which could be used to do what you are talking about:

```
create function dbo.GreatCircleDistance
    (
    @Latitude1  float,
    @Longitude1 float,
    @Latitude2  float,
    @Longitude2 float
    )
returns float
as
/*
FUNCTION: dbo.GreatCircleDistance

    Computes the Great Circle distance in kilometers
    between two points on the Earth using the
    Haversine formula distance calculation.

Input Parameters:
    @Longitude1 - Longitude in degrees of point 1
    @Latitude1  - Latitude  in degrees of point 1
    @Longitude2 - Longitude in degrees of point 2
    @Latitude2  - Latitude  in degrees of point 2

*/
begin
declare @radius float

declare @lon1  float
declare @lon2  float
declare @lat1  float
declare @lat2  float

declare @a float
declare @distance float

-- Sets average radius of Earth in Kilometers
set @radius = 6371.0E

-- Convert degrees to radians
set @lon1 = radians( @Longitude1 )
set @lon2 = radians( @Longitude2 )
set @lat1 = radians( @Latitude1 )
set @lat2 = radians( @Latitude2 )

set @a = sqrt(square(sin((@lat2-@lat1)/2.0E)) + 
    (cos(@lat1) * cos(@lat2) * square(sin((@lon2-@lon1)/2.0E))) )

set @distance =
    @radius * ( 2.0E *asin(case when 1.0E < @a then 1.0E else @a end ))

return @distance

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but I think there is an error here:

```
SELECT @LatRange = @Radius / ((6076 / 5280) * 60)
```

The (6076 / 5280) part will always evaluate to 1.

Comment: If this constant will always be the same, just replace it with `69.04545`

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available in-box for SQL Server 2012 and above.  See [Query Spatial Data for Nearest Neighbor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor):

```
DECLARE @g geography;  
DECLARE @h geography;  
-- SRID 4326 specifies the use of WGS 84 coordinate system (same as GPS)
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.360 47.656)', 4326);  
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326); 

-- Returns 995 meters 
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h);
```