# Compare points inside a list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple list of points `List<Point>` which I populate using the mouse. Like, when I click the mouse, the location is added into the list. The problem is that the new location is added at the bottom of the list. What I want to do is, when I click the mouse, search all the existing points in the list and return the closest point to the mouse location, and insert the new point after that one.

I've been searching the web for hours and I can't seem to find a solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: show us your point class

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to loop through your points? How to find the distance from the mouse?

Comment: This is the list: List<Point> MousePoints = new List<Point>(); and i add items like this: MousePoints.Add(new Point(x, y));

Comment: Are you using the built-in System.Drawing.Point?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is compare the existing points in the list and get the one that is closest to the mouse location.

Comment: Your question should ask how to compare Points to see if they're close to each other or not, not how to insert it into a List.

Comment: The closest point will be the one that has the closest straight line. Second criteria - the one that is higher (larger Y) and third criteria is one that on the right (smaller X) - but this is your business -specific. And this can be calculated if you imagine a right triangle with two points being ends of the longest side (c). Then a2 + b2 = c2. Done

Comment: comparing two points http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032331/determine-if-two-points-are-near

Comment: How is the Point class defined ? Are the x and y coordinates integers ? Also, how big is the plane, or grid, within which the user is allowed to click ? In other words, what are the min and max values of both X and Y axis ?

Answer (score 5):

The `List<>` class contains [an `.Insert()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) to do just that.  When you search the list and find the "closest" element (however you define that logic), you can get [the index of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352278.aspx) that object in the list.  Then just insert the new one after that index.  Something like:

```
var closestPoint = FindClosestPoint(listOfPoints, newPoint);
var index = listOfPoints.IndexOf(closestPoint);
listOfPoints.Insert(index + 1, newPoint);
```

Getting the closest point itself should be a simple matter of geometry.  You have two X/Y coordinates on a plane.  The distance between them is [the square root of the sum of the squares of the axes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).  So you just need the element where that value is the smallest.  Something like this:

```
var closestPoint = listOfPoints
                   .Select(p => new {
                       Point = p,
                       Distance = Math.Sqrt(
                           Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p.X - closestPoint.X), 2) +
                           Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p.Y - closestPoint.Y), 2)
                       )
                   })
                   .OrderByDesc(p => p.Distance)
                   .First();
```

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how to get the closest point.

Comment: My only problem with that is, if user clicks many times and there are many points to loop, the list may get skewed. May be better to register clicks in the queue and then add them to the list on the different thread?

Comment: @Adrao: I've updated the answer with an attempt to determine the nearest point.  The math itself should be straightforward enough, just getting the hypotenuse of the axes between the two points and finding the element with the smallest hypotenuse.  This is free-hand and untested, so some tweaking may need to be done.

Comment: @T.S.: True, this isn't entirely performant.  The overall math is simple enough, it's just a matter of making this a meaningful user experience for the application after that.