# Cannot convert from int to System.Drawing.Point when comparing coordinates

Tags: c#, int, point

I want to check if two sets of coordinates are close to each other. I had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13032393/5798798), which suggested using the Pythagorean formula to calculate the distance between two points.

The two sets of coordinates I'm comparing is the current position of the mouse, and preset coordinates under the variable `point`

```
if(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point.X - this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position.X), 2) + Math.Pow(point.Y - this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position.Y), 2) < 50))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Distance between the points is less than 50");
}
```

The variable `point` has the point data type.

I am using `this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)` instead of `Cursor.Position` because I want to get the coordinates relative to the form, instead of relative to the screen. However using this gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert from `int` to `System.Drawing.Point`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've put `.X` and `.Y` at the *wrong side*: first convert the point, then take its coordinate.

Another issue is `< 50` position

```
if(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point.X - this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X, 2) + 
             Math.Pow(point.Y - this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y, 2)) < 50)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Distance between the points is less than 50");
}
```

You may want to *extract* `this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)` to have `if` *more readable*:

```
var cursor = PointToClient(Cursor.Position); 

if(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point.X - cursor.X, 2) + 
             Math.Pow(point.Y - cursor.Y, 2)) < 50)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Distance between the points is less than 50");
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Cannot convert from bool to double`

Comment: @The Codesee: I see; `< 50` is at wrong postion as well; please, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

`PointToClient` expects a `Point` as argument by you are passing an int. So change this

```
this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position.X)
```

to:

```
this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X
```

And also

```
this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position.Y)
```

to

```
this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y
```